# 'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Tags: android, ionic-framework, cmd, ionic2, hybrid-mobile-app

I am working with ionic2  and want to  access my installed application code,

Now when i run the command "**adb devices**" in cmd , it is showing error as

"'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

what should i do ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to Your Android SDK `platform-tools` in `cmd` and then try `adb` command

```
C:\"your path "\sdk\platform-tools
```

Answer (score 1):

In cmd set path to `platform-tools` and then use `adb` command.

Like I have put my `sdk` in `E: drive` so I have to set below path.

```
E:/sdk/plateform-tools
```

after setting hit `adb devices`.

Comment: thinks  fro solution it works now

Comment: If you find any of answer given here is helpful then please up vote that answer and appreciate their effort.

Comment: i tried it buddy , but dont have that right from stackoverflow yet ,sorry for that

Comment: @DevangMistry we are giving answers after checking all things.

Comment: warmly thanks for you help brother , and i appreciate that .

Answer (score 0):

Try in platform tools 
go to

```
yoursdk path\sdk\platform-tools
```

and press <kbd>Shift</kbd> and right click => **open command window here** and use **adb**

and try again or add path variable

Comment: thinks  fro solution it works now

Comment: @DevangMistry then please accept one